# Javascript, can I pass a reference to a current object to function within an object literal definition?

Tags: javascript, function, object-literal

Good Morning,

I have a function that takes an options hash as it's parameter, can I call that function inside an object literal definition? Like this

```
 function dataCallback(opts) {

    var rowSelector = opts['id'] + ' .gridContent';
    var liSelector = opts['id'] + ' li';

    return function(args) { //do something with opts... 
              return; 
    }
    //omitted...

} 

var obj = { x : {id = '#someId1', callback: dataCallback(//what can I pass here? this? x? obj.x? nothing seems to work...)}
           , y : {id = '#someId2', callback: dataCallback(///???, this? y? obj.y?)}  };
```

I hope my question makes sense.  Perhaps I worded it incorrectly in the title. Anyways, if someone can straighten me out here I would truly appreciate it.  Thanks for any tips or tricks.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Look at the logic of what you're trying to do - even if it was possible to do that - it would result in infinite recursion. In order to pass `obj.x` into `dataCallback`, it would have already had to invoke `dataCallback`... which requires `obj.x` to be defined already. If you explain what your end goal in trying to do this is, it'll be much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Goodmorning? It's 6:59 PM here

Comment: @Kooilnc and its 1pm here. there are other parts of the world u know, aside from your bubble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood is that you want to assign the return value of the function to a property of the object and passing the object itself to the function. Is this correct?

You cannot do this in one go. You have to separate the steps:

```
var obj = {
    x: {id: '#someId1'},
    y: {id: '#someId2'}
}; 

obj.x.callback = dataCallback(obj.x);
obj.y.callback = dataCallback(obj.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function dataCallback(opts) {

    var rowSelector = opts['id'] + ' .gridContent';
    var liSelector = opts['id'] + ' li';

    return function(args) { //do something with opts... 
        return;
    }
    //omitted...
}

var obj = {
    x: {
        id: '#someId1',
        callback: function(){dataCallback(this)}
    }, y: {
        id: '#someId2',
        callback: function(){dataCallback(this)}
    }
};

obj.x.callback();
```

in order to do `dataCallback(this)` you need to put it in an anon fn or else this does not refer to the object, it refers to the global `DOMWindow`

Comment: This is not doing anything with the return value of `dataCallback` (the function). I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nothing works, because JSON is not self-referenceable, only Firefox now supports Sharp Variable in JSON so that you may write like this:

```
function dataCallback(opts) {
    // your logic here
    return function(args) { /* logic here */ };
}

var obj = {
    x:#1={
        id: '#someId1',
        callback: dataCallback(#1#)
    },
    y:#2={
        id: '#someId2',
        callback: dataCallback(#2#)
    }
};
```

Note that Sharp Variable is only supported by some versoin of Firefox and will possibily be removed at future point, so use it at consideration.
Syntax in Sharp Variable is extremely strict so that you should write "x:#1={" without any extra space in each character.

For reference of Sharp Variable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Sharp_variables_in_JavaScript

Comment: JSON is the literal notation of object in javascript, so when you define an object using **{ /\* properties /\* }** it is a JSON.

Comment: OK, maybe I incorrectly explain something. in my post I have said **JSON is not self-referenceable** so that by pure JSON it is **totally impossible** to implement what the author wnat in a single JSON block. My goal is to provide some alternative way which is called **Sharp Variable in javascript**, I incorrectly called it **Sharp Variable in JSON**, sorry for that.

Comment: and the author does not strictly require JSON either. Yes for some point the way I provided is totally useless because it only works in Firefox, but actually we cannot archieve the goal by pure **Javascript Object Notation**

Comment: What @Neal means is that object literals are not JSON, despite the similar syntax and the similar name. JSON is a data exchange format which syntax is a subset of JS object literals. Many people make the mistake and call object literals JSON. For more information: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Felix, i believe you taught me that on a previous question